# Method similar to << and >> operators with is not loosing bits

Tags: c#

Example:
`x = 0xF0AA`, now when I do `x = x << 8`, I will get `x == 0xAA00`. 
Right side (8 bits) of new value is filled with zeros. Is there a method int .NET Framework which can fill this bits with that bits from left side (with disapeared part)?
Result should be `x == 0xAAF0`.

Comment: Sounds like you want a bit/byte rotate operation.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_shift

Comment: I've not tested this as I've not got visual studio on this computer but just `(x<<8) + (x>>8)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is called a circular shift. It's easy enough to emulate with two shifts and an or.

```
UInt32 RotateLeft(Uint32 n, int howManyBits) {
    return n << howManyBits | n >> (32 - howManyBits);
}
```

Comment: After I post my question, I was enlighten how to achieve it like you show it now.